# Storing data offline with javascript

Tags: web-development, javascript

My question is about storing data offline and potentially whether I will need to bring in an outside programmer or could this be learned within a few weeks?

The website I am working on will have an interface where users will login and go through a series of quizzes in the form of checkbox, drop down menus, and others. Each page/quiz area could have 20-100 total checkboxes in a series of 3-5 rows because of the comprehensive nature of course.

This I can do - I know how to code the quiz and return a correct or incorrect answer based on each individual checkbox and present a cumulative score (ie: you got 57% correct).

The issue lies in the fact that I would like to save the users results and keep them informed of their progress. When they complete all of the quizzes, I would like to have a visual output of their performance in each area. Storing the output from their results offline is where I think I may run into a problem with my lack of coding experience. I would also like to have a sidebar with their progress of each section (10-15) with a green percentage completion bar or a % correct which would draw from this.

I have never had to code something that stores information like this offline - so back to my question - would it be better to learn the language needed or bring in a coder/developer for the back end stuff.

Comment: Why does this need to be stored offline?

Comment: See my answer to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/135612/saving-mobile-application-data-when-no-service/135614#135614

Comment: It appears - from a comment below - that you don't mean "offline" as that implies that it will be stored on the client machine when the machine is not connected to the internet. What you need is to be able to store the data on your server. You can't do this directly from the client - you need to have something running on your server to do this. You can then access the "something" from your javascript and have the application run substantially in browser

Answer (score 2):

Its very easy and you can learn it in like an hour or so tops.

you can also consider using some library like this

http://www.jstorage.info/

I am using it for one of my project.

Comment: Morons - thanks for that link. I didn't think about saving it to the users computer.

Comment: Wait - they will need to be stored offline because I would like the user to be able to use more than one computer.  If they log in from a different computer I would like them to have all of their information available.

Comment: @Walker then this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: You could have a server-side and client-side representation of the data. Then, implement a bi-directional sync by using a modified timestamp on each entry. If the timestamps don't match, incrementally replay the changes until they do before they can take another quiz (ie, change the data any more). That way you get both remote and local data persistence.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not critical that the answers be super-secure, just throw it into a cookie. All you need is some kind of a string codified into quiz numbers and answers right? You can parse it and evaluate to establish whether they were correct and spit out percentage complete/correct etc based on the info I'm assuming you already have baked into your JS.